# Oracle Apex How to retain value of item from previous page and use in all other pages

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a project application.

Tables

Project:
PID_PK
ID
NAME
YEAR

Project_Details:
ID_PK
ID(FK to ID column in Project)
Lead
Manager
Requirement

and similarly there are many child tables linked with the main table.

The first page of application shows lov dropdown wih project name, where i am saving the id using dynamic action.
ID is hidden item P1_ID.

Now i need to carry forward this id to other pages which have child tables as sources.

On the main page with dropdowns there's just one button submit that directs to the other pages, in this case project details and so on.
I want to retain and use the P1_ID item as condition for all child table pages would be: id=:P1_ID.

If i use redirect to page option the id is not getting retained.

1. How do i retain and use the P1_ID for all pages
2. Second requirement is, if the project details exist, i.e. PROJECT_DETAILS.ID is not null, then it would open the form with existing value.
   If it is null, the page should still load with blank form to create new project.

I know its bit vague but any leadswould be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single thread - can you update your question to only have a single one ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the question about the P1_ID. You could create an application item F_PROJECT_ID and set it with computation on the main page. Then on each of the pages you create a computation before the value is needed to set the Px_ID to the value of item F_PROJECT_ID. If you do it this way you can also reference the value in lists that are shared across multiple pages.

Comment: Hi, can you provide any sample application computation?

Comment: You don't need an application computation, you need a computation on every page that you need the id on. Say on page 15 you have the project id, then you'll create a computation on page 15 on page item P15_ID of computation type "Item" with value "F_PROJECT_ID"

Comment: Did my reply help ?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks